# How to pass a table parameter from lua to C++ through a lightuserdata object?

Tags: c++, lua

I have registered a function that creates a lightuserdata to be used by C++ and lua. that part is working fine when I tested using simple variables, ints and strings. I can create my lightuserdata in lua without errors when it's strings and ints. however when I try to use tables it gets more complicated

```
std::string aString = lua_tostring(lua,-4);
```

first parameter being correct as it is supposed to be a string

```
if (lua_type(lua,-3 == LUA_TTABLE))  //is true so i know it recognizes it as a table
{
    auto t = lua_gettable(lua, -3);

    size_t tableLen = lua_rawlen(lua, -3); // also gives me the correct size
    lua_settop(lua, 1); //this discards the rest right? which i don't want.
    //luaL_checktype(lua, 1, LUA_TTABLE); //using this crashes the application expecting
// table but getting string
    lua_getfield(lua, 1, "a");
    lua_getfield(lua, 1, "b");
    lua_getfield(lua, 1, "c");
    lua_getfield(lua, 1, "d");
    lua_getfield(lua, 1, "e");
    std::cout << lua_gettop(lua) << std::endl; //after using the getfields i get the new table size 
//correctly (i assume, it turns 1 more value than expected, i think it's the table itself.
    //int a = luaL_checkinteger(lua, -5); //these don't work as they expect numbers but get nil
    //int b = luaL_checkinteger(lua, -4);
    //int c = luaL_checkinteger(lua, -3);
    //int d = luaL_checkinteger(lua, -2);
    //int e = luaL_checkinteger(lua, -1);
    std::cout << lua_tointeger(lua, -2) << std::endl; //returns always 0

}
```

Trying to ignore the table and get the rest of the stack gives me an violation error on 0x000000, though the 3rd value debugs correctly as what is supposed to be and the 4th is empty, even though it passes correctly if i don't use table.

is What I'm trying to do possible proceeding like this?

any comment to the right direction would be appreciated.
also, what should I use if I don't know the name of the key in the table?

Comment: I see no C code, only C++

Comment: sorry corrected it, didn't think it matters that much since they're pretty similar

Comment: `lua_getstring(lua,-4);` which Lua version you're using? It must be something ancient, since there's no `lua_getstring()` starting somewhere around Lua 4.0.

Comment: @Vlad i rewrote the code above as i had lots of debug lines so didn't wanna copy paste everything. but u r right. it's lua_tostring. I'm using 5.2

Comment: `I can create my lightuserdata in lua` - nope, you can't create it from within Lua. It does exist within Lua state, but can be only created by native code. `lightuserdata` is essentially a plain pointer to opaque data structure. Why do you have it involved in parameter passing "through lightuserdata" ?

Comment: @Vlad Sorry I guess I failed to explain that part. English isn't my native language so I have a hard time explaining sometimes. 

The lightuserdata doesn't matter at this point since I can't get a table parameter from a function. The function itself creates the the userdata after being called from lua. so lua calls the registered function, which retrieves the passed parameters and creates the object accordingly which then pushes it as lightuserdata. that works fine as long as I use simple variables.

Comment: @Jimomo: "*The lightuserdata doesn't matter at this point*" Then why did you mention it? You spent the first paragraph talking about it, it's even in your title, but you're saying it's not the problem? It's also not clear exactly what your code is trying to accomplish with regard to this table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if (lua_type(lua,-3 == LUA_TTABLE))  //is true so i know it recognizes it as a table

Big error here, or you didn't post the actual code.

You're not checking the type of the value under index -3, you're asking the type of the value under index `false`, since `-3 == LUA_TTABLE` is clearly `false`.

Whatever crash that happens after that "check" - is a result of this error. It will recognize as a table anything that is not `nil`.

Comment: thank you. good catch, that is how i wrote it in my code.for some reason that whole if statement runs so didn't double check it. With further testing though. I can work with a table if the table is sequence type x = { 1,4,5,8,2}

by using:  `size_t count = lua_rawlen(lua, 1);`  
`for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)`  
`{`  
`lua_rawgeti(lua, 1, i);`  
`int Top = lua_gettop(lua);`  
`std::cout << lua_tonumber(lua, Top) << std::endl;`  
`lua_pop(lua, 1);`  
`}`  
changing the table to x = {a= 1, b= 4}etc breaks things. I can't seem to get table len with `lua_len`, gives returning 0 as length

Comment: I accepted your answer since after fixing the if statement and testing things I had tested before, it worked. not getting the length since that always gives me 0 but at least I can use the lua_next to iterate through the table and get the key value pairs.

Thanks a bunch. any idea how to preserve the order of the table elements though?

Comment: @Jimomo The length is only defined for a sequence part of a table. And you can't influence the order of iteration on a hashed part. Typically that's totally ok.